# Empty reply from server when trying to redirect HTTP to HTTPS in nginx as a reverse proxy for jenkins

Tags: nginx, http, redirect, https, jenkins

I’m running Jenkins behind Nginx and I use Let’s Encrypt for the SSL Certificate. If I access the site via `https://jenkins.mydomain.de/`, everything works fine. But when I access it via `http://jenkins.mydomain.de/`, Firefox says “Connection was reset.” and curl says “Empty reply from server”

How do I debug this? I don’t really know where to look for the problem. The nginx logs don’t contain any thing about it. I suspect that the section about port 80 in the configuration down below is invalidated by some other directive, but I don’t know how I would investigate that.

```
$ curl -svL http://jenkins.mydomain.de/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying my.ip.add.ress...
* Connected to jenkins.mydomain.de (my.ip.add.ress) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: jenkins.mydomain.de
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host jenkins.mydomain.de left intact
```

When using telnet to speak to the server, the connection is closed as soon as I hit return only once (i. e. after `GET / HTTP/1.1`).

Even though Firefox doesn’t have a problem with the SSL Certificate, curl does:

```
$ curl -svL https://jenkins.mydomain.de/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying my.ip.add.ress...
* Connected to jenkins.mydomain.de (my.ip.add.ress) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
} [data not shown]
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
```

My Nginx configuration:

```
upstream jenkins {
    server localhost:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name jenkins.mydomain.de;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    # Replacing $server_name with $host does not work either.
}

server {
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name jenkins.mydomain.de;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.mydomain.de/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.mydomain.de/privkey.pem;

    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080 https://$server_name;
        proxy_pass https://jenkins;
    }
}
```

Nginx is listening on port 80:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3895/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1048/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3895/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::41117                :::*                    LISTEN      19911/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      19911/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1048/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::49208                :::*                    LISTEN      19911/java
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the same `server` block as you for port 80 and 301 redirection, it worked on my setup, with Jenkins *(I don't think the application backend has any influence but just to be sure)*. The problem I got was firewall not open for port 80.
You should verify your own firewall.